# To be able to find more than one link

Tags: php, regex, detection

Code can only find and change one image link in the text. If it's more than one, it doesn't work. How can I get it to detect multiple image links?

```
$sad222 = "somthing text bla bla bla ...... https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg asdas https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg  121das";
    function findAndChangeImgLinksInStrings($string)
    { 
        $reg_exUrl = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/m'; 
        if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $urls, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
            foreach ($urls as $url) { 
                $newLinks = $url[0][0];
                if (strstr($newLinks, ":") === false) {
                    $link = 'https://' . $newLinks;
                } else {
                    $link = $newLinks;
                }
                $exploded = explode($link, $string);
                $string_before = $exploded[0];
                $string_after = $exploded[1];
                if (strtolower(substr($link, 0, 7)) == "http://" || strtolower(substr($link, 0, 7)) == "ftps://" || strtolower(substr($link, 0, 8)) == "https://" || strtolower(substr($link, 0, 6)) == "ftp://") {
                    if (strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".jpg" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".jpe" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".jif" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".jfi" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".gif" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".png" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".bmp" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".dib" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".ico" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 5, 5)) == ".jpeg" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 5, 5)) == ".jfif" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 5, 5)) == ".apng" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 5, 5)) == ".tiff" || strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) == ".tif") {
                        $imageCode = erisimKoduOlustur();
                        getFile($link, '/images/' . $imageCode . strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)));
                    }
                }
                
                return $string_before . '<a class="noteImageInQNote" href="https://example.com/images/' . $imageCode . strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) . '" target="_blank"><img class="noteImageInQNote" src="https://example.com/images/' . $imageCode . strtolower(substr($link, strlen($link) - 4, 4)) . '"></a>' . $string_after;
            }
        }
        
        return $string;
    }
    
    echo findAndChangeImgLinksInStrings($sad222);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up your code and search in a much simpler way using PHP native functions.

First of all the pattern: `/(https?|ftps?)\:\/\/[^\s]*/` which will find **http** and **https** as well as **ftp** and **ftps**. With that you have all matches in one array.

Using *pathinfo()* you can extract the extension and check if it is in an array of wanted extensions.

```
$sad222        = "somthing text bla bla bla ...... https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg asdas https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg  121das";

$findImageUrls = function (string $string): array {
    $images = [];
    preg_match_all('/(https?|ftps?)\:\/\/[^\s]*/m', $string, $urls);
    foreach ($urls[0] as $url) {
        if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),
                ['jpg', 'jpe', 'jpeg', 'jif', 'jfif', 'jfi', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'dib', 'ico', 'apng', 'tiff', 'tif'])
        ) continue;
        $images[] = $url;
    }

    return $images;
};

print_r($findImageUrls($sad222));
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg
    [1] => https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg
)
```

#### Update

Based on your comment you want to manipulate the URLs. Here's an example on you may do this.

```
$imageUrlsToHtml = function (array $images, string $text): string {
    foreach (array_unique($images) as $image) {
        $text = str_replace($image, "<a href='$image' class='noteImageInQNote' target='_blank'><img src='$image' alt='image'></a>", $text);
    }

    return $text;
};

echo $imageUrlsToHtml($findImageUrls($sad222), $sad222);
```

#### Output

> somthing text bla bla bla ...... <a href='https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg' class='noteImageInQNote' target='_blank'><img src='https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg' alt='image'></a> asdas <a href='https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg' class='noteImageInQNote' target='_blank'><img src='https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg' alt='image'></a>  121das

Comment: Thank you for your help, the goal of my code is to find the image links in the text and replace them with a different link. I wanted to integrate your code with my code, but I couldn't.

Comment: Tell me what you want to replace. Your initial code is somewhat unclear for me. You want to linkify them and change domains? What is the image code?

Answer (score 1):

This function will split your string up by spaces then if they're web links that include .jpg put them into an array. Tested with your example string.

```
$teststring = 'somthing text bla bla bla ...... https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/150x100/public/article/main_image/2022/08/02/984246-1125154792.jpg asdas https://www.indyturk.com/sites/default/files/styles/800x600/public/article/main_image/2022/11/18/1055251-759331593.jpg  121das';


function detectimages($string){
    
    $strings = explode(" " , $string);
    
    $imgsarray = array();
    
    foreach($strings as $string){
        
        if(str_contains($string , "https://") && str_contains($string , ".jpg")){
            
            array_push($imgsarray , $string);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var_dump($imgsarray);
    
}

detectimages($teststring);
```